# Highlighting around textboxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox, custom-controls, border

I am trying to draw a highlighted border around a custom textbox control so that I can reuse the highlighting feature for each new program I create. My approach so far has been to override the paint event in the control library (dll) after the custom property I have created is set. The code for the control is below.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

<ToolboxBitmap(GetType(Button))>
Public Class Textbox_Custom
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Public Event OnEnterKeyPress()
    Public Event MissingInfo_Change As EventHandler
    Dim iMissing_Info As Boolean
    Dim iCharacterInput As Cinput

    Public Property CharacterInput As Cinput
        '<Browsable(True), DefaultValue("AllowAll")>
        Get
            Return Me.iCharacterInput
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Cinput)
            Me.iCharacterInput = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Missing_Info As Boolean
        '<Browsable(True), DefaultValue(True)>
        Get
            Return iMissing_Info
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            iMissing_Info = value
            **MyBase.Refresh()**

        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
            RaiseEvent OnEnterKeyPress()
        End If

        Select Case Me.iCharacterInput
            Case Cinput.CharactersOnly
                If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            Case Cinput.NumericOnly
                If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        **If iMissing_Info = True Then**
            Dim rect As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(Me.Size.Width + 2, Me.Size.Height + 2))
            Dim pen As New Pen(Brushes.OrangeRed, 2)

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect)

            e.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

Public Enum Cinput
    AllowAll
    NumericOnly
    CharactersOnly
End Enum
```

While debugging I have set a breakpoint in the OnPaint override (lines **), but it never hits it. I then put a breakpoint in the Set section of the Missing_Info property where I am trying to invalidate the control to redraw. It does hit the MyBase.Refresh breakpoint so I don't understand what I've missed.

I realize there have been several other posts on this topic, but from what I can tell they seem to require putting panels behind the control. I feel like I should be able to include this action in a custom control and not have to code a new highlighting section for each new project. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you on your specific question, but wouldn't it be easier to just set the textbox border to none, and then draw a rectangle in whatever color you want around the textbox?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any way to replace the existing border with a custom type or color. If I just changed the color of the existing border style (don't know how to do that either) I don't think it would be wide enough to draw attention to it.

Comment: You're going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to build your own custom textbox that will allow border colors. Rather than going that route, I strongly suggest you set the textbox border to None, and then draw a rectangle in whatever color you'd like around said textbox. This is the most commonly used method to achieve special borders. You can even adjust the rectangle width to make it stand out as much as you'd lke

Comment: Thanks Eric, I decided to just change the control background to a semitransparent red. I guess I was hoping there was some reasonable way to implement it within the control. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to just go with changing the control background to a semi-transparent red color which should be obvious enough for what I'm doing.